# Create dockerFile along with java agent return error

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, docker-machine, open-telemetry

I am trying to dockerize a spring-boot application along with otel-javaagent but no-luck getting below exception all the time,

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:
-javaagent:/agent/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar -Dotel.traces.exporter=otel -Dotel.metrics.exporter=none … (more) … Error occurred during initialization of VM agent library failed to
init: instrument Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing :
/agent/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar
```

This is my dockerFile,

```
FROM maven:3.8.3-amazoncorretto-17

RUN mkdir -p /agent
ADD https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/releases/latest/download/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar /agent/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar

ENV JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-javaagent:/agent/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar \
-Dotel.traces.exporter=xray \
-Dotel.metrics.exporter=none"

VOLUME /srv/logs

ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} device-backend.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/device-backend.jar"]
```

Below logs where generated when I generate a jar file,

```
 [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/maven:3.8.3-amazoncorretto-17@sha256:02af1d85d3cd514a6489e2bc1c35c9af826d02f92297fd1c505b66cafad30213
     https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/releases/latest/download/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar [done: 1.023s]
     [background] read source files 34.40MB [done: 2.319s]
     [2/4] RUN mkdir -p /agent [cached]
     [3/4] ADD https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/releases/latest/download/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar /agent/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar [cached]
     [4/4] COPY app/target/*.jar device-backend.jar [cached]
     exporting to image [done: 20ms]
```

I believe the jar file was downloaded and present in the path I mentioned but still the container is getting restarted with above exception.

Answer (score 0):

> Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing :
> /agent/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar

this usually means that the file is not present, not readable (e.g. permissions), or it is not a valid jar file